# Why does this code return me 6561?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I was learning function calling **by reference** and function calling **by value**, and I am facing problem in discovering why it is returning me 6561.

In my main function I called a function `f(p,p)` , where p is initialized to 5 before call.

And I defined function f as:

```
int f(int &x, int c)
{
    c = c - 1;
    if (c == 0)
        return 1;
    x = x + 1;
    return f(x,c)*x;
}
```

Why does this code return **`6561`**?

Comment: I think the last line of your function invokes undefined/compiler-dependent behavior, since the variable x as a multiplier could be either x from before the function was called or after depending on the order the compiler evaluates the factors f(x,c) and x in.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod I'm sorry, I am not getting what you just said... please elaborate...thanx

Comment: Okay, let's try something else - the first time the function f is called, what is the value of the multiplier x? Is it 6? Is it 10? It depends on how the compiler treats the line. The standard doesn't tell how to handle this.

Comment: @James McLeod  I took x = 9 and after mutiplying it 4 times it gives me 6561, so Is hit-n-trial is the method to solve such problem ?

Comment: Since x is passed by reference changing x inside of f() changes it outside of f() (simplified). That James is talking about is this: the x which the recursive call to f() is multiplied with is (might be) changed by the recursive call to f(). The question is now if f(x,c) is multiplied with the "original" x or with the x that is changed by the call.

Comment: @EricSchaefer yes, but 9*9*9*9 is the only expression that satisfies the answer... So Do I need to consider that f(x,c) is multiplied with the original x each time.... ??

Comment: This evaluation (9*9*9*9) might turn out differently on a different compiler. That is what James meant with "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is a rather complicated one to learn about references, because to understand the implication of the first parameter being passed as a reference you first need to understand the nature of the recursion.

Let me repeat your code:

```
int f(int &x, int c)
{
    c = c - 1;
    if (c == 0)
        return 1;
    x = x + 1;
    return f(x,c)*x;
}
```

apparently there is another function somewhere which contains code like this:

```
int p = 5;
result = f(p, p);
```

The first thing to note is the fact that it is calling itself recursively.
The parameter c is used as a counter to limit the number of recursive calls. It is decremented in the first line of `f()` and when it is reduced to `0` the recursion stops (by just returning `1`).

Since `p` is initialized to 5 the recursion will terminate after 5 calls.

In the 4th line of `f()` the parameter x is incremented.

And finally in the last line the recursive call is made passing a reference of x and the decremented c.

Apparently the function return 6561 as result, which is 9*9*9*9 (which is equivalent to 9*9*9*9*1). This is a hint to what is going on here.

Lets follow the data through the recursions:

#0: entry: x=5, c=5, just before the last line: x=6, x=4
 #1: entry: x=6, c=4, just before the last line: x=7, x=3
 #2: entry: x=7, c=3, just before the last line: x=8, x=2
 #3: entry: x=8, c=2, just before the last line: x=9, x=1
 #4: entry: x=9, c=1, just before line 3: x=9, x=0 (returns at line 3, return 1;)

With the `return 1` no further recursive calls are made. Now we are returning backwards through the recursions:

#3: x=9 => return 1*9; (evaluates to 9)
 #2: x=9 => return 9*9; (evaluates to 81)
 #1: x=9 => return 81*9; (evaluates to 729)
 #0: x=9 => return 729*9; (evaluates to 6561)

Now why is x=9 in all four recursion levels? Because it is passed as a reference, not a value. This means that x is basically the same variable in memory for all recursive calls to `f()` (actually all x's are aliases to p). Not only is x=9 just before returning from the first recursion level, p will be 9 after `f()` returns.

Although you are passing p for both parameters, x is the same on all recursion levels and x is not (passed by value). This should explain the difference.

You should read up about references if you don't understand this yet. As stated, this function is a rather complicated one for learning about references and it does not seem to be very useful.